# Is it possible to cast directly into write?

Tags: c, unistd.h

While i was creating my own malloc, I used write to print some value.

I don't have any problems to print value, I just create a char variable to stock my number and print it, but I don't understand why the cast doesn't work.
The prototype of write is:

`ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)`

So i cast my number in void * without any result.

```
int nb = 3;
char numb = nb + '0';

write(1, (void *)(nb + '0'), 1); // Display nothing
write(1, &numb, 1); // Display 3
```

Someone can explain why the first write display nothing?

Comment: `(void *)(nb + '0')` is a pointer to an invalid address - I'm surprised it doesn't segfault.

Comment: Why are you not checking `write`'s return value for errors?

Comment: @PaulR System calls don't segfault, they `EFAULT`.

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer ! Can i have more information about it ? Why is it a pointer to an invalid address ?

Comment: *`write(1, &numb, 1); // Display 34`* - That would surprise me. Especially if it's printing two characters when you told it to only print one.

Comment: @GregLoupy You're taking a random integer (82 in this case) and casting it to a pointer. How would that be a valid address?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but it's not a *cast*, it's a *compound literal*:

```
write(1, (char[]){nb + '0'}, 1);
```

or:

```
write(1, &(char){nb + '0'}, 1);
```

Comment: Thank you it was exactly what i was searching for !! :)

Answer (score 1):

`(void *)(nb + '0')` is trying to dereference memory at the actual value of `nb + '0'`, as if that value was an address.  `(nb + '0')` is not an l-value, so you can't use the `&` operator on it either. What you should be doing is:

If you're on a little-endian system (seems to be OP's case):

```
nb += '0';
write(..., &nb, ...);
```

If you're on a big-endian system:

```
char foo = (nb >> (CHAR_BIT * (sizeof(int) - 1))) & 0xff;
foo += '0';
write(..., &foo, ...);
```

Comment: `nb` is an `int`. What do you expect `write` to do with that?

Comment: @melpomene Given that OP added the numeric value of char `'0'` to it, I assume he's aware of what he wants `write` to do with it

Comment: @melpomene it works because integers are stored in memory in little endian, so the first byte in memory is (34 + '0'). write doesn't treat it as an int

Comment: This answer is wrong and endian-dependent if `nb` has type larger than `char`.

Comment: @R.. Updated my answer to account for big-endian systems

Comment: @GovindParmar Yes, right... `numb` was the char... I think, the better way is to just assign it to a char to be independent from endianess troubles.

Comment: @Ctx Don't feel bad; I thought `nb` was a `char` as well until R.. pointed it out

Comment: @AsafRosemarin "*integers are stored in memory in little endian*" - citation needed.

Comment: @GovindParmar: You just reimplemented the brokenness on big endian with explicit endian logic rather than by reading the first byte of the `int` in memory. The right fix is just `char foo = nb;` But it doesn't solve OP's goal of avoiding a temp.

Answer (score 0):

Casting to void* only means it should treat the given value as a void pointer.
But the given "address" is 34 + '0' which is obviously invalid. 
You must give `write` a pointer so it is not possible to do something like that. you must store the value you want to print somewhere in the memory and give a pointer to that location.

Comment: But `(nb + '0')` doesn't have an address.